# Can FileMaker Server v11 support FileMaker v9 clients?

Tags: mac-osx, filemaker

See title.  Apparently FMServer v8 won't run on 10.6.x, so will upgrading the server component be sufficient or will we need to update all the v9 client licenses as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest updates to both (FMServer 11v2 and FM 9v3), apparently the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

We're running FMServer 11v2 on our 10.6 server, with our FM 8.5 clients on 10.4.11 without problems.